# Use mysql query to check timestamp value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get date from database where the logout date is smaller than status posted date.

My current query which is running is as follows :

```
SELECT user.logout, status.date 
        From user 
        Inner join status
        ON user.uid=status.uid;
```

This can get the date for both logout date and posted date, but the problem is how to compare the dates. I'm using timestamp to store the date, so the format will be same,

I have tried something like this :

```
SELECT if user.logout < status.date 
        From user 
        Inner join status
        ON user.uid=status.uid where date(user.logout) < date(status.date)
```

but it doesn't work. Please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show us actual data or PHP code?

Comment: What is the `SELECT if`? I don't know that in MySQL. What columns of the DB do you want to select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like this, as instead of comparing in select part, you should do it in where clause.

```
SELECT user.logout, status.date 
FROM user 
INNER JOIN status ON user.uid=status.uid 
WHERE user.logout < status.date
```

Comment: Just like that! No complication required

Answer (score 0):

if date's are in time stamp then use `date()` keyword..

```
SELECT
    USER .logout,
    STATUS .date
FROM    USER
INNER JOIN STATUS ON USER .uid = STATUS .uid
WHERE   date(USER .logout) < date(STATUS .date)
```